# Can using a under powered laptop charger make my notebook shut down under heavy load?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, battery, power

I have a XMG P501 gaming laptop based on Clevo P150HM models at the moment connected to an under powered laptop charger. It is shutting down when under heavy load (3dmark, some games in particular) even if neither the CPU nor the GPU temperatures are in critical ranges. I tried removing the battery, it does not make a difference. It works just fine when idling or playing low demanding games; it's able to charge the battery.

The original power supply got fried by plugging it to an electric outlet when travelling on a bus and since I could not find the original model at any local shop, (it's a FSP-Group FSP180-ABAN1 180W 19V/9.47A power supply) for the time being I have to work with the highest powered charger I was able to find around here and that is a 19V/7.5A power supply  (I've already ordered an original replacement but it will be delivered in about two week).

My question is: can the temporary under powered universal charger I've bought be the culprit of those shutdowns? Or is internal circuitry/motherboard damage an option since it all happened because of a power surge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. That's the short answer.

It ***could*** be that. Many laptops identify when the power is attached, and the charging circuits for the battery will engage, and isolate the battery power from supplying the laptop, while at the same time powering the laptop from the main supply. When you run on the charger, you are running both the laptop, and simultaneously charging the battery. The power draw may be substantial. Additionally, the power supply will probably engage it's own overload circuitry, and shut down, which may be enough to glitch your system.

There are a lot of 'maybe' and 'could' in that.

It may also be a simple case of overheating your CPU, or graphics chip, causing a thermal overload/shutdown.

If you chose to use a power source that is not specified to support your system, you will get unspecified results... that's the bottom line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, there are a lot of maybes indeed. Anyway the shutdowns also take place after that the battery has been removed. I doubt it's a overheating issue at least not regarding to the CPU/GPU since their temperatures are never high enough to induce a thermal shutdown.

Comment: Got the new original laptop charger, everything is working correctly and the notebook is not shutting down when under heavy load any longer.

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be shutting down due to lack of power, but I'm skeptical.  Assuming that the battery is in good health, I would expect that the battery alone should be able to power the laptop, and in a sense, act as an uninterruptible power supply.

How reproducible is the problem?  If possible, I would try to trigger the failure while running on the batter alone, and the A/C power disconnected.  If it still shuts down, then obviously the underpowered power adapter is not to blame.

Comment: When on battery the GPU (a 580M GTX) is throttled because there is not enough power available so its clocks are way lower than when it's plugged to a power source (which would explain why it shuts down rather than starting to run on battery), so I sadly cannot reproduce it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak on much detail about it, but I know I have used an under-powered charger in the past on a computer and this DID happen, but once I switched back to the normal charger I was supposed to everything worked just fine. Though as others have pointed out there are more possibilities than just that.